# How to use the same traits for different item

Tags: google-smart-home

we have a smart tub with a pump and a blower. I need to be able to say:

turn the pump/blower on/off (using the same trait)

but google refuse us to have more than one id

Is there a way to to it without more than 1 id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a device with multiple things that can toggle on and off, you can use the [Toggle trait](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/toggles):

> This trait belongs to any devices with settings that can only exist in one of two states. In other words, this trait covers all available custom binary settings on a device.